# Unable to install mbstring for php7.1 on server running multiple PHP versions

Tags: php, package-management, php7

My Centos6 webserver is running php 5.6 and php 7.1 (webmin/virtualmin).  I already have mbstring installed for php 5.6, but I also need it for 7.1.
When I do `yum install php71w-mbstring` I get the following error:

`Error: php71w-common conflicts with php56w-common-5.6.40-1.w7.x86_64`

I thought the package names being different (php71w vs php56w) were supposed to prevent this type of conflict?

How can I get mbstring for php 7.1 installed without breaking php 5.6?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get PHP 7.1 from?

Comment: @MichaelHampton that's a good question - it shows webtatic in the yum list, but those don't appear to be installed.  It may have been installed by webmin/virtualmin. How else can I tell where it was from?